# Black and White printing on Epson WF-2750

Tags: printing, epson-workforce

When opening the printersettings for the Epson WF-2750 in windows, I don't find the options colour like I have for other printers (e.g. HP).
How can I chnage to deafult B&W printing?

Comment: According to the [manual](https://files.support.epson.com/docid/cpd5/cpd51270/index.html), if you've loaded the Epson driver, it should be staring at you on the main tab of the printer settings window.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNNT0.png

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps:

- In Control Panel open Devices and printers option.
- Find your printer. Right click on the printer's name.
- In the drop menu that opens click on Printing Preferences.
- A new window opens then click on COLOR tab.
- Check the "Black & White" or "Grayscale" option
- Click on Apply, then OK.

Comment: Right Jacob but then I have only the tabs Layout and Paper/Quality and under paper/quality  only tray selection but no possibility to select Color